# HTML doesn't automatically interpret character code

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

I have a HTML page with buttons and text. This page can be changed from French to English to Spanish. The special characters (é, è, à, etc...) are rendered in their HTML code (e.g., `à` is `&#224;`).

When I assign special characters in a text input (`type="text"`) the character are rendered correctly but when I assign these characters to an input button (`type="button"`) value, it shows the raw code.

If I use the browsers Developer Tools (F12) to change a letter in the value it will refresh itself and interpret the character.

Is there something I'm missing ? Or is it just a bug ? I have tried to use the HTML name code and the Javascript character escape sequence also, but with no luck.

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: "*when I assign these characters to a input button value*" - are you doing that by JS or in the HTML source as an attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Unicode in JS, not HTML character code. See example.

```js
$('#one').val('&#224;');
$('#two').val('\u00e0');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&#224;</p>
<input id="one" type="button" value="a" />
<input id="two" type="button" value="a" />
```

Comment: why are there different codes? Why not using only one?